# pip only collects package (matplotlib) not installs it

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, anaconda

I am trying to setup object detection tensorflow api on my system by following [this](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) tutorial. All the steps work but matplotlib installation is not working. Pip is only collecting the matplotlib and not installing it. However if I install other package like Pandas, it installs properly.

[image: Command prompt image can be seen here]

Comment: Have you tried importing it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Console input and output is made of text. It should be shared _as text_, not as screenshots. Text can be copied and pasted into a text editor! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be efficiently searched! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be consumed by users of assistive technologies, like screenreaders! Screenshots cannot :-(. [Please give text the respect it deserves instead of banishing it to inaccessible image formats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577).

Comment: Try using the `--no-cache-dir` option.

Comment: I tried importing it but it gives the expected Module not found error.

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem. ```--no-cache-dir´´´ does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on Windows 7 64 Bit (Python 3.7) that worked for me:

1. Open `cmd` (console) in Windows. If you are on Windows 10 use powershell and enter `cmd` in powershell.
2. Navigate into the "Scripts" folder of your virtual environment using `cd`. In your example this should be "c:\tensorflow1\models\research\Scripts"
3. Verify that you are calling the python.exe in this folder (and therefore of this virtual environment) by typing `python` and hitting enter. Try to import matplotlib. This should *not* work since the package is not installed yet.
4. Do **not** activate the environment.
5. Use `python -m pip install matplotlib` to install the package.